# How to create command property of a button control inherited in second user control and behaves differently according as more than one buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

1. How to create the properties like command and content of the  user control's button in second user control which is inherited from first user control .
2. How to replace the image which is used inside button of the first user control and is inherited in second user control.

In xaml: create a button as a user control containing a button which contains an image. This button is inherited in second user control and behaves differently according to image icon.

```
<Button>
  <stackPanel>
    <Button>
      <ButtonStyle>
         <Style TargetType = "{x: Type Button}">
           <setter property = "Template">
             <setter.value>
                <controlTemplate TemplateType = "{x: Type Button}">
                   <ControlPresenter width= "{TemplateBinding Width}"/>

                    </controlTemplate >
                   </setter.value>
                 </setter>
              </Style>
           </ButtonStyle>
             <Image source = ".jpg"  >
         </Button>
   <stackPanel>
</Button>

<!-- Button is inherited in second user control and behaves differently according the functionality of more than one buttons  -->

<Window>
      <StackPanel>
          <btnUserControl command=  />   <!-- I did not find the command property here  -->
      </StackPanel>
 </Window>
```

Comment: Check out the answer and see if that helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need `custom control inheriting Button` so that it can inherit all properties of Button and you can extend on that by providing your custom properties.

Create a custom control say `ImageButton` and create dependency property `ImageSource` which can be binded from outside -

```
public class ImageButton : Button
{
   public ImageSource ImageSource
   {
      get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), 
                                          typeof(ImageButton));        
}
```

Define `default template` for `ImageButton` in App resources -

```
<Style TargetType="local:ImageButton">
  <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ImageButton">
          <StackPanel>
             <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
             <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}"/>
          </StackPanel>
       </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now you can bind it from other UserControls like this -

```
<local:ImageButton Content="TestContent"
                   Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                   ImageSource="Images/a.jpg"/>
```

where `local` is namespace where `ImageButton` resides.